# Numpy appending from a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an assignment in which I have to map a name from the list to a specific integer in the array (hope I used the terminology correctly). I wrote this code but it is not working. Why is this so, and how can I make it work?

```
list_1 = ['sentosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'sentosa']
beta = np.array([])
for x in list_1:
  if x == "sentosa":
    np.append(beta, [1], axis = 0)
  elif x == "versicolor":
    np.append(beta, [2], axis = 0)
  elif x == "virginica":
    np.append(beta, [3], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy arrays have a fixed size, they are not really appendable.  What you're doing will be dead slow even if you fix the bugs.  Use a plain list instead, and convert it to a NumPy array at the end if necessary.

Comment: @Amateur1: Great.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You can "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

##### how to fix your code

[`numpy.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) is not in place, so you would need to assign back the output:

```
list_1 = ['sentosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'sentosa']
beta = np.array([])
for x in list_1:
    if x == "sentosa":
        beta = np.append(beta, [1], axis = 0)
    elif x == "versicolor":
        beta = np.append(beta, [2], axis = 0)
    elif x == "virginica":
        beta = np.append(beta, [3], axis = 0)
```

##### how to do what you want efficiently

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `return_inverse=True` option to factorize your data:

```
np.unique(list_1, return_inverse=True)[1]+1
```

output: `array([1, 2, 3, 3, 1])`

Answer (score 0):

To map the list of strings to unique integers, one has to first find the unique strings and then do 1-1 mapping of the strings to integers in the original list of strings.

```py
list_1 = ['sentosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'sentosa']

# create unique list of  names
unique_list = set(list_1) # Unique list {'sentosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'}

# create mappings from names to integer (id)
string_to_integer = {name: idx+1 for idx, name in enumerate(unique_list)}

# map initial list of names to ids
k = [string_to_integer [name] for name in list_1 ]
```

output:

```
3, 2, 1, 1, 3
```

**Another possible way -**

```
list_1 = ['sentosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'sentosa']

mydict={}
i = 0
for item in list_1:
    if(i>0 and item in mydict):
        continue
    else:    
       i = i+1
       mydict[item] = i

k=[]

for item in list_1:
    k.append(mydict[item])
```

```
1, 2, 3, 3, 1
```

**Then shift to `numpy array`**

```
arr = numpy.asarray(k)
```

I hope this will help you to do your assignment.